# php mysql news error

Tags: php, mysql, html

I recently added a news system that uses myysql/php, it works perfectly, but it gives some errors when adding html.

For example if I add a youtube video it will add / or \

What do I change on the codes below to store html into database?

This is what the HTML ends up looking like after:

Comment: Please format your code to make it readable. This could be is but a respect to people whom you're asking for help.

Answer (score 2):

This may be nothing more than some unstripped slashes. It appears you are escaping slashes before saving the data (good job!), but you don't appear to be removing those slashes when you go to show the data. Try the following out when echoing:

```
echo stripslashes( $myrow['title'] );
```

Comment: That did the trick, Joanthan. Thank you!

Comment: Happy to help, @HilraJannar. Since your new to StackOverflow, it's encourage you accept the answer that best solved your problem. This awards both you and the answer's author a bit more reputation.

Comment: @HilraJannar don't use this answer. This guy have no clue. You **don't** have to strip whatever slashes when you get your data from the database. That means you have your data spoiled somewhere else - so, you have to make your code not to add excessive slashes. cure the decease, not the symptom.

Comment: @YourCommonSense If the slashes were added to properly place it within the query string, then you would need to remove them in order to display the HTML, since slashes preceding quotes isn't valid markup (unless you're patching it through JavaScript into `innerHTML`). Would you mind telling me where I'm wrong?

Comment: You need to learn some mysql if you care to answer questions on the matter. That's all.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Again, please tell me *specifically* where I'm wrong.

Comment: `If the slashes were added to properly place it within the query string, then you would need to remove them` <-- HERE

Answer (score 1):

You most likely got [magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) enabled.
 If so you should check for this and [stripslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) accordingly.

```
function magic_quotes_strip($value){
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
        if(is_array($value)){
            return array_map('stripslashes',$value);
        }else{
            return stripslashes($value);
        }
    }else{
        return $value;
    }
}
//Strip all slashes from post array before handling
$_POST = magic_quotes_strip($_POST);
```

Then do your normal mysql escaping before input, without the worry of double escaping:

`$title = mysql_escape_string($_POST['title']);`

**Notes:**

`PHP_SELF` is a XSS vulnerability you should [htmlentites](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) that or remove it so its just `action=""`

`$_SESSION[usr_name]` your using `usr_name` as a constant it should be `$_SESSION['usr_name']`

Comment: If you have magic quotes on, you have to strip slashes not only for mysql, but for the whole site. Excessive slashes in the cookies are as bad as as in HTML. The article you linked to tells you so.

Comment: Yeah thats obvious hence `stripslashes accordingly` meaning on input **NOT!** output, i have had hosting in the past with it on, and a simple user function on all POST/GET inputs has sufficed, Where do I mention cookies?

Comment: I DO mention cookies. One have to strip magic slashes from all the spoiled data, not only data going to mysql strings. Please refer to http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php for the details.

Comment: That's way better. I'd also suggest to clean not only POST but all affected variables, like described in the http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php

Answer (score 0):

There is a some place in your code that does add excessive slashes for no reason.
You have to find this place and remove excessive slashing.

This could be a notorious [`magic_quotes_gpc`](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) ini setting. You have to either turn it off or, if you can't, strip these useless slashes at the very top of your configuration file, using the code from the link above.

This could be some silly useless "ultimate cleanup function". You have to find it and remove slashing from it.

This could be somewhere else, say inside of the `generate_wysiwyg()` function or anything.

Remember: doing just stripslashes() is but an ugly crutch, correcting your data only in one place, leaving it spoiled elsewhere.